# how to loop this array

Tags: php

These are the post variables.

How can I put these in loop?

Where 'master_customer_id' and 'firstname' are the name attributes 
and the array in them is the values retrieved and I need to save these values to the database.

Values are dynamic, means to say array could go upto any number, here I'm just saying 3 key value pairs.

Thank you in advance.

```
  array
  'master_customer_id' => 
    array
      0 => string '1' (length=1)
      1 => string '1' (length=1)
      2 => string '1' (length=1)
  'firstname' => 
    array
      0 => string 'a' (length=1)
      1 => string 'a' (length=1)
      2 => string '' (length=0)
```

I am also adding the form

```
<?php 

for($i=1;$i<=3;$i++){            
?>

    <input type="hidden" name="master_customer_id[]" value="1" />
First Name: <input type="text" value="" name="firstname[]"/><br/>

<?php  }  ?>
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to retrieve from the array?

Comment: Use `foreach` to loop through arrays. You can nest them.

Comment: `Values are dynamic, means to say array could go upto any number` then how are you going to save them in database columns? Please provide a hint of your database schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['master_customer_id']); $i++) {
  echo $_POST['master_customer_id'][$i];
  echo $_POST['firstname'][$i];
}
```

or

```
foreach ($_POST['master_customer_id'] as $key => $value) {
  echo $value;
  echo $_POST['firstname'][$key];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($array as $key => $value)  
{  
    foreach ($value as $key1 => $value1)
    {   
        echo $value1;  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is guaranteed that you have the same number of `master_customer_id` and `firstname`, you can loop it like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['master_customer_id'])) {
  for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['master_customer_id']; $i++) {
    $customer_id = $_POST['master_customer_id'][$i];
    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'][$i];
  }
}
```

Comment: "If it is guaranteed that you have the same number of master_customer_id and firstname" -- "Values are dynamic, means to say array could go upto any number"

Comment: but you have the same number of `master_customer_id` and `firstname`. Or you could have like 5 `master_customer_id` but just 2 `firstname`?